# Tick/Check only tickable checkboxes via console

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to tick all checkboxes on a page, however some of them are greyed out and I don't want these ones ticking,

Using the below I can tick everything but this is not suitable, is there anything I can use to only tick available checkboxes?

```
$(":checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: Try `$('[type=checkbox]:not(":disabled")')`. It should fix your problem.

Comment: Also you should indent your code by four spaces instead of a &gt; (which is for quotes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greyed out means disabled right. 
use `not(":disabled")` not filter of jquery to filter disabled inputs.
check below code snipet

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").not(":disabled").prop("checked",true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" >
<input type="checkbox" >
```